# Reduce columns that whose names matches a pattern

Tags: r, datatable

I am trying to create multiple columns in my datatable that represent the sum of columns that match the given pattern by row.

```
df <- data.frame(first_column = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Tango", "Alpha, Beta,Alpha", "Alpha,Beta,Charlie", 'Tango,Tango,Tango,Tango', 'Tango,Tango,Tango, Tango', 'Tango,Tango,Tango, Tango , Alpha,Beta,Charlie, Alpha, Alpha ,Alpha '),
                 number_1 = 1:9,
                 number_2 = 11:19,
                 number_3 = 2:10,
                 number_4 = 12:20) 

testing <- df %>%
  mutate(number_1 = as.numeric(number_1),
         number_2 = as.numeric(number_2))%>%
  as.data.table 


testing3 = testing[,`:=` ("Total 1" = Reduce(`+`, grep("number_1|number_2", names(testing), value = TRUE)),
                          "Total 2" = Reduce(`+`, grep("number_3|number_4", names(testing), value = TRUE)))]
```

This is what I have tried to far to no avail. What I should see is Total 1 row 1, 12 and Total 2 row 1, 14

but I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `grep` returns only the column names with `value = TRUE`, we need the value of the columns,  Use `.SD` to subset the columns from the column names

```
library(data.table)
testing[,`:=` (
   "Total 1" = Reduce(`+`, .SD[, grep("number_1|number_2", names(.SD),
              value = TRUE), with = FALSE]),
    "Total 2" = Reduce(`+`, .SD[, grep("number_3|number_4", names(.SD), 
     value = TRUE), with = FALSE]))]
```

-output

```
> testing
                                                          first_column number_1 number_2 number_3 number_4 Total 1 Total 2
                                                                <char>    <num>    <num>    <int>    <int>   <num>   <int>
1:                                                               Alpha        1       11        2       12      12      14
2:                                                                Beta        2       12        3       13      14      16
3:                                                             Charlie        3       13        4       14      16      18
4:                                                               Tango        4       14        5       15      18      20
5:                                                   Alpha, Beta,Alpha        5       15        6       16      20      22
6:                                                  Alpha,Beta,Charlie        6       16        7       17      22      24
7:                                             Tango,Tango,Tango,Tango        7       17        8       18      24      26
8:                                            Tango,Tango,Tango, Tango        8       18        9       19      26      28
9: Tango,Tango,Tango, Tango , Alpha,Beta,Charlie, Alpha, Alpha ,Alpha         9       19       10       20      28      30
```

---

If there are multiple sets, we may also create a named `list` , `Filter` the `list` elements based on the occurence of names

```
lst_names <- list(c("number_1", "number_2"), 
                 c("number_3", "number_4"), 
                 c("number_5", "number_6"))
names(lst_names) <- paste("Total", seq_along(lst_names))
lst_names_sub <- Filter(length, lapply(lst_names, function(x)
        intersect(x, names(testing))))
testing[, names(lst_names_sub) := lapply(lst_names_sub, function(x) 
         Reduce(`+`, .SD[, x, with = FALSE]))]
```

Comment: Interesting. I knew that .SD allowed for subsets but I thought you had to specify the .SD with the .SDcols = argument

Comment: @GaetanoDona-Jehan `.SD` is subset of data.table.  If we don't specify `.SDcols`, `.SD` returns all the columns.  Here, as you are using multiple subsets, we are not specifying `.SDcols`, instead use the column index/column names to subset the subset of data.table

Comment: Actually is there a way ignore if columns do not exist? So have the above code but sometimes I have number 5 and 6 and sometimes I do not.

Comment: @GaetanoDona-Jehan You may check with `exists` or can create a condition to check the ncol of `.SD[, ...]`

Comment: @GaetanoDona-Jehan I updated the post based on your comment.  Please check if that helps